# Data goes null after few successful requests - Node service App pool caching

Tags: node.js, express, iis, caching, application-pool

I have a service built using Node and Express and MongoDB as database. Service is hosted on IIS.
There is a side filter panel section in the application. Since that filters' master information does not change often (Data Size is in KBs), I use basic Node caching technique(no npm package) to avoid going to database on each page load request. Below is the sample Node code:

`//main index.js file`

`SetFiltersList() function is called as Node service is first initialized on IIS, or, when app pool recycles.`

```
(async () => {
    await init.SetFiltersList();
})();
```

`//init.js (utility file)`

```
let filtersList = null; // filterList object that keeps list of Filters as cached object

const SetFiltersList = async (_error) => {   
        //This is a MongoDB database call
        result = await defaultState.DEFAULT_STATE.GET("FiltersList");      
        filtersList = result.filters;
}

//Get filters call
const getFiltersList = () => filtersList;

module.exports = {
    FiltersList: getFiltersList
};
```

`//Controller.js`

```
 const GETFILTERLIST = async (req, res, next) => {
            res.send(init.FiltersList());
  }
```

`//Controller Route`

```
approuter.route('/GetFilterList/')
     .get(Controller.GETFILTERLIST);
```

**Problem**

After few calls, Filters start returning null and strangely when I recycle the Application pool, the Filters starts coming again for sometime and this repeats after period of time.

Any thoughts whats going wrong here and how I can overcome this?

Comment: Is there any error message or warning in event viewer? It is temporarily impossible to determine whether the problem is caused by IIS or Node-cache, but you can set an [expiration time](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache#change-ttl-ttl) for Node-cache first.

Comment: I am not using any npm package  like Node-cache. It is direct data caching using Node/Express and App pool. Note that SetFiltersList() in the above code is called on Index.js file as the app starts on app pool and data is cached.